# HTML form, link error

Tags: php, html

I have a very weird problem.
I'm coding login system and i have two buttons in form; one is for submitting and second is link and is used to send user to register page.
My problem is that when i click that link form is submitted instead of redirection.

Here is link to page:

http://takeaprize.pl/login.php

And page code:

```html
<?php
include_once 'secure/core.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $settings->getSiteTitle(); ?> - Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $settings->getMETAdescription(); ?>" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $settings->getMETAkeywords(); ?>" /> 

    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="assets/css/minimal.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/vendor/jgrowl/css/jquery.jgrowl.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="bg-1">
    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">
      <!-- Make page fluid -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Page content -->
        <div id="content" class="col-md-12 full-page login">


          <div class="inside-block">
            <img src="assets/images/logo-big.png" alt class="logo">
            <h1><strong>Welcome</strong> Guest</h1>
            <h5><?php echo $settings->getSiteTitle(); ?></h5>

            <form id="login_form" class="form-signin" action="">
              <section>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                </div>
              </section>
              <section class="controls">
                <a href="forgot.php">Forgot password?</a>
              </section>
              <section class="log-in">
                <button class="btn btn-greensea"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Log In</button>
                <span>or</span>
                <a href="register.php"><button class="btn btn-slategray"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Create an account</button></a>
              </section>
            </form>
          </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /Page content -->  
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Wrap all page content end -->
  </body>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: provide your code so others can help you

Comment: `<button>` type by default is `submit`. `<button>` you placed inside your `<a>` will then submit your form. You may add `type="button"` or **better** drop second (useless) `<button>` and style `<a>` with `btn btn-slategray`.

Comment: thanks! completely forgotten about this

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Post your comment as an answer, silly.

Comment: @Tek it should better be a duplicate, I'm sure there are 1000 answers about this but I'm pretty lazy to search them